# Should I use binary/xml files in my .NET application?

Tags: .net, xml, file, sqlite, binary

I have worked as web developer for several years and have always used a database to store the information, or sometimes XML files.

Now I'm developing a small application (Windows form). This application need to store data but the amount of data are not going to be too big. The information will be complex like customers information, but the number of customers will be 20/30...more or less.

And now I have doubts. I think that use a database (even SQLLite) is too much. I like XML but I need a good performance so I think that probably binary files are a better solution.

I have used XML a lot, but never binary files.

Are binary files used in current .NET projects? Should I forget binary files and use XML files? Should I use SQL Lite?

When binary files are useful?

I hope anyone can tell me something about when to use binary files.

Thank you and I'm sorry for my English, is not my mother tongue.

Comment: You may rise a big discussion but...no, binary files are evil 99% of times (performance? features? error recovery? compatibility?) A small compact single file-single user database is much more scalable. Of course if this data will change often over time. If you just need to store settings or a few read-only information then System.Configuration is for you (addendum...oh for a more complex scenario I really love System.Xaml...)

Comment: P.S. "...I like XML but I need a good performance...". I don't think you'll ever hit that limit for such small amount of data.

Comment: @Adriano meh; nothing wrong with binary... but the decision should be based on real concerns, not imagineering

Comment: @MarcGravell I agree, maybe "...are evil..." is little bit too strong but I dislike a _custom_ binary format unless it is _absolutely necessary_ (because it's not _human readable_, you have to write your own _tools_ to manage it, _interop_ with other software is harder, it's not _self-documenting_ and _scaling up_ is all on your shoulders)

Comment: @Adriano, compatibility is not a problem because it is going to be a small application for myself. What could be a problem is when any entity change with new properties. In this case XML is much easy to manage.

Answer (score 1):

.NET is very comfortable with XML from early framework versions including 1.0. XML schema was introduced by .NET when the rest of the world was still using DTDs and plain ASP was main Microsoft's HTML CGI web technology. Take a look at "resources" concept and yes app.config is the .NET web.config. Built in settings is the way to go -> there's a nice mechanism to localize your text resources too.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the built in Settings files, as explained in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869.aspx) MSDN article.

> The .NET Framework 2.0 allows you to create and access values that are persisted between application execution sessions. These values are called settings. Settings can represent user preferences, or valuable information the application needs to use. For example, you might create a series of settings that store user preferences for the color scheme of an application. Or you might store the connection string that specifies a database that your application uses. Settings allow you to both persist information that is critical to the application outside of the code, and to create profiles that store the preferences of individual users.

Though discussing VS 2005 and .NET 2.0, it is still relevant.

Comment: I thought in Settings but I the data is too big/complex for settings. For instance, a list of 30 customers with all their details...is not just the theme of the application, or the default time out for some operation.

Comment: @Vallekano Settings are just a simplification for configuration classes, you can easily persist a collection of entities.

Answer (score 0):

I would create Customer Model class and whole application should work with List of that classes, and then just serialize that list to disk when you need to save your data, or when app is starting deserialize that list from storage file.

I would certainly use XML serialization, mostly because is human readable, and performance should be no problem with so small amount of data.

Comment: Yes, this was my first idea. The only problem is that I have to read everything at the beginning and keep it in memory (actually it is not a problem). The only problem that I see with XML files is add a new item or read a specific item because is expensive in time (without caching). But probably in my case the best solution is work in memory because won't be too much changes in the data.

What I see is that nowadays no one use binary files...